# Sencha Touch 2.1 native (android) app not getting json from remote (it works on PC)

Tags: android, json, proxy, sencha-touch, touch

I created my first Sencha touch 2 app by watching this video (http://youtu.be/5F7Gx0-W-M4) and it has a store page structured like this:

```
Ext.define('FirstApp.store.Places',{
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',

    config:{

        autoLoad:true,
        model:'FirstApp.model.Place',
        proxy:{
            type:'ajax',
            url:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyCFWZSKDslql5GZR0OJlVcgoQJP1UKgZ5U',
            reader:{
                type:'json',
                rootProperty:'results'
            }
        }
    }
})
```

The after-build (after running "sencha app build native") package work very well on my MAC (all browsers) but the generated app (i am running it on my nexus phone) works but doesn't collect any data from the google maps json.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The example you are referring is using google map's place search API. You can not use this API when you build the app  for mobile phone with `proxy` set to `ajax` . Basically, you can not use any resource that is outside your domain. Like if your site is at **yourdomain.com** and there is **someotherdomain.com**, then you can't make ajax request to this **someotherdomain.com** from **yourdomain.com** unless that domain allows you to. In this case, your mobile app is not having any domain. You are just loading a page inside webview.

The reason is, ajax will not be able to load cross-origin resources. App build works on browsers because I believe you're using chrome with `--disable-web-security` flag. To work with CORS you need to use JsonP proxy. It's the only way if you're packaging for mobile app. If in a case, you own the server ( not in this context though ) then you can allow CORS by setting appropriate headers like

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

or

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com/resource
```

Try setting proxy to JsonP .

Comment: Thank you so much for this ultra-clear explanation. I'd give a good vote to your answer but i don't have the required reputation.